# Rspec Error, create action in all models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

My spec/controllers/undertakings_controller_spec.rb is below.

```
    require 'rails_helper'
    RSpec.describe UndertakingsController, type: :controller do
        describe '#create' do
         let(:undertaking_params) do
           attributes_for(:undertaking)
         end
         it 'increases undertaking by 1' do
              user=create(:user)
              login_user user
              expect{post :create , undertaking: undertaking_params }.to change(Undertaking, :count).by(1)
         end
       end
      end
```

I delete other actions in this spec file because the test of other actions works.
and My controllers/undertakings_controller.rb is below.

```
      class UndertakingsController < ApplicationController
           def create
            @undertaking=current_user.undertakings.build(undertaking_params)
            @undertaking.asking_id=params[:asking_id]
           if @undertaking.save
             flash[:success] = "依頼の申し込みに成功しました。"
             redirect_to @undertaking.asking
           else
            @asking=@undertaking.asking
            render 'askings/show'
          end
        end
```

and My models/undertaking.rb is below.

```
      class Undertaking < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :user
        belongs_to :asking
        has_many :comments
        has_one :deciding
        validates :content , presence: true , length: {maximum: 800}
        validates :title , presence: true , length: {maximum: 20}
     end
```

My error is below.

```
       No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"undertakings", :undertaking=>{:title=>"MyString", :content=>"MyText", :result=>false}}
```

Routes of the create action is below.

```
     asking_undertakings POST     /askings/:asking_id/undertakings(.:format)                   undertakings#create
```

I think maybe the error causes there is not :asking_id in spec file.
But I can't understand what I should do.
Please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As defined in your routes, your create path needs a `asking_id` to be passed as params. So, modifying your rspec line from

```
post :create , undertaking: undertaking_params
```

to

```
post :create, asking_id: <asking-id>, undertaking: undertaking_params
```

should work.

I see you are not creating an `Asking` in your rspec. So, you will first need to create one and then pass its id in the `post :create` call.

**UPDATE**

You can create `Asking` object in your rspec with factory-girl, given you have defined the factory for `Asking` model.

```
asking = create(:asking)
post :create, asking_id: asking.id, ...
```